# jQuery Mobile: How to 1) remove/hide the title bar from the dialog box and 2) just remove/hide the "X" icon from the title bar?

Tags: jquery, css, dialog, jquery-mobile

I saw some way to hide the title bar and icon in the title bar in a dialog in jQuery UI but not in jQuery Mobile.  Does anyone know how to do that in jQuery Mobile?

1. remove/hide the title bar from the dialog box?
2. remove/hide just the "X" icon from the dialog box?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this to css, You won't get the close(cross) in your header of the dialog box.

.ui-dialog  .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-notext
            {
                 display:none;
            }

Answer (score 1):

2)

```
<style>
.ui-dialog .ui-header .ui-btn-icon-notext  { display:none;} 
</style>
```

1) is a little bit tricky because the title bar is formed with a H1 tag that also causes the round edges for the top, but you can hide it anyway:

```
<style>
.ui-dialog .ui-header .ui-title  { display:none;} 
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1a)** If you want to remove just the title:

```
.ui-dialog h1 { opacity : 0; filter : alpha(opacity=0); }/*hide any h1 elements in the dialog (should only be one)*/
```

**1b)** If you want to remove the whole title-bar:

```
.ui-dialog > .ui-header { display : none }/*hide the whole header*/
```

**2)** To hide just the "X" (Close) button:

```
.ui-dialog > .ui-header > a { opacity : 0; filter : alpha(opacity=0); }/*Hide all links in the header*/
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate how each of these solutions look: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/2Z66R/2/

I use `opacity` rather than `display` for hiding the "X" (Close) button and the title text so that they will still occupy the space they are in. For instance if you make the title text completely transparent rather than setting `display : none` then the rounded corners stay intact on the top of the dialog (check-out the jsfiddle above).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the css if you want this change to be in effect everywhere. check out the class that is used for the toolbar and the X and add to your css those classes and put display:none; in there